# mongodb mongoose query for a point where coordinates=[longitude,latitude]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have successfully created a schema which stores longitude,latitude of type point. I have indexed it using 2dsphere . I'm using mongodb and mongoose.

Here is the code snippet of my schema

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        loc :  { type: {type:String}, coordinates: [Number]},
        locationName: String,
```

```
})
```

locationSchema.index({loc: '2dsphere'});

I can successfully insert location data in the table.

I would like to do something similar to "select loc from DB where coordinates = [longitude,latitude]" using mongoose and in mongodb .

Using mongodb ,I tried using db.collections.find({loc:{type:"point",coordinates:[longitude,latitude]}) and several other syntactic variations of the same query, it didn't work.

Could someone please point in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it with the callback ?

```
db.collections.find({loc:{type:"point"}}, function(err, data){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(data)
  // Do a for loop where data.cordinates === longitude,latitude..
})
```

Comment: When I use the above code , I add a condition **if(data.length==0)** with a console.log statement , and always the console.log inside the if condition is executed

Comment: Even when data is not empty ? Did you checked `data.length` is not outputting 0 ?

Comment: In mongoDB console,  the query below works when you want to search for a document with a given latitude and longitude  **db.collection.find({loc.coordinates: [lon,lat]}, {_id:1}, callback)**